# Modal ajax form stuck on success message when refired

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a page with roughly 20 enquiry buttons. Each button fires the same modal ajax PHP form. The form system works as it should, sending an email and triggering the success message. The success message displays inside the form tags but the rest of the form disappears leaving just

tags.

The success message has a close button which closes the modal but the problem is that when I click any of the other enquiry buttons on the page they fire the modal but its still stuck on the success message.

Is there a way of using the modal close button as a sort of clear form trigger?

This is the ajax script im using…

```
<script>
    function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
    function submitForm() {
        _("sendenquiry").disabled = true;
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait…';
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
        formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
        formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open( "POST", "enquire.php" );
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                    _("enquiry_form").innerHTML = '<p>Thanks '+_("n").value+', we will be in touch shortly.</p>'; 
                } else {
                    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("sendenquiry").disabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send( formdata );
    }
</script>
```

This is my html

```
<!--enquiry modal--> 
            <div class="enquire-form-modal ef-effect" id="efmodal">
                <div class="ef-content">
                    <div>
                            <form class="enquire-message" id="enquiry_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Please fill out your enquiry below and we'll quickly get back to you.</legend>

                                        <div class="">
                                            <label class="" for="">Name</label>
                                            <span><input type="text" id="n" class="" name="" placeholder="My name" required></span>
                                        </div> 

                                                <div class="">
                                                    <label class="" for="">Email</label>
                                                    <span><input type="email" id="e" class="" name="email" placeholder="My email" required></span>
                                                </div> 


                                                <div class="">
                                                    <label class="" for="">Enquiry</label>
                                                    <span><textarea id="m" class="" name="" placeholder="My enquiry" required></textarea></span>
                                                </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <input id="sendenquiry" type="submit" value="SEND"> <span id="status"></span>
                                        </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        <button class="ef-close">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="enquire-form-overlay"></div>        
<!--enquiry modal end-->
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I’ve tried various things but nothing is working yet. If you need more code please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when they click another button?

Comment: I'm hoping I can allow a user to send several different form enquiries from the same page. That UX means I need to work out how to present a fresh modal form after the previous forms success message. Hope that makes sense. My thinking is it would be great to use the close success button <button class="ef-close">Close</button> to clear foem somehow but I understand the button is outside the form tags.

Comment: By replacing the content of the form with the message you lose the form. If you have a bunch of forms on your page, and they had different IDs, then you could do it the way you are now as long as you passed the ID to your `submitForm()` function. If you are using one form, then you should use a message box or overlay that notifies the user of the message.

Comment: Thanks Mr Glass. I'd not considered the multi form option since having 20 forms on a page seems slightly clunky. I'd prefer to have the one form modal approach but only if it can be done. The success message is still inside the form tags but obviously the fields etc are no longer present to make space for the message. when page is refreshed the form is available again so ther must be some way of doing it with ajax or jQuery perhaps. I did a fiddle of the form here but without Ajax and success message – https://jsfiddle.net/dommcloughlin/56vyp2cf/23/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're replacing all of the form's html when the ajax call is complete. Try using the "status" div for housing the success message. Then, perhaps a simple `setTimeout` will suffice for clearing the message.

```
<script>
    function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
    function submitForm() {
        _("sendenquiry").disabled = true;
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait…';
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
        formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
        formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open( "POST", "enquire.php" );
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = '<p>Thanks '+_("n").value+', we will be in touch shortly.</p>'; 
                } else {
                    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }

                // clear the "status" message after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function() {
                    _("status").innerHTML = "";
                }, 5000);
                _("sendenquiry").disabled = false;
            }
        }
        ajax.send( formdata );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Jason. I tested this as it is and the form hangs on "please wait". I then added some <p> tags and a message inside your status and the form disappears after clicking send but no success message appears or email is sent.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not much more I can do to help you. The code looks fine to me. Make sure there are no errors in "enquire.php" and that it is returning the proper status codes. I recommend using Chrome Dev Tools for this. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: Thanks Jason, appreciate your time!